# How to position elements consistently across devices in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm building an app that includes functionality similar to image tagging on Instagram. Users can tap on an image, and choose a tag from a list. I then save the tag and location to Firebase.

Here's the main code that creates and positions those tags:

```
// Get the location of a tap

handlePress(evt) {
  this.top = (evt.nativeEvent.locationY * 100) / SCREEN_HEIGHT;
  this.left = (evt.nativeEvent.locationX * 100) / SCREEN_WIDTH;
}

// Create a new View component using the location

tagItem(item) {
    const newView = {
      locationX: this.left,
      locationY: this.top,
      item,
  };

// Add the new tag to a list of tags

    this.setState({
      tagList: this.state.tagList.concat([newView]),
  });

};
```

Is using `SCREEN_HEIGHT` and `SCREEN_WIDTH` - derived from Dimensions in React Native - the best way to position elements?

I have this working fine in the simulator, and on a real device of the same size. However, I want to make sure this works across multiple device sizes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As long as the image view is the same aspect ratio on every device, this should be reliable as you’re essentially storing the top and left values as a percentage of the height/width.